# StorageWorks 2700 with 2 servers

Tags: cluster, installation

Is it possible to connect HP Storageworks 2700 with two i/o modules ( A and B ) to two ML350 servers with P812 Smart Array controlers installed - to share the same storage space ( dual domain ). I´ve tried to check several cabling options, but with no success ( with some wrong cabling the server doesn´t have connect to 2700, or both servers connect to 2700 with different ways, so if I add partition on first server, the other server doesn´t see it )

Answer (score 1):

This kind of two way (and it has to be two way, three way won't work) SAS LUN sharing *is* possible, others have asked this question on here before by the way. The only real problem you'll get other than possible supportability issues is that you absolutely HAVE to use a cluster-aware file system otherwise your entire filesystem will corrupt almost immediately.

Most people do this kind of block-level sharing using fibre-channel/FCoE or iSCSI by the way.